# Anonymize a Google Images URL

Tags: google-image-search, url-shortening

If I search Google Images for `mountains of madness lovecraft`, I get something like this URL:

> https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1019&bih=805&q=mountains+of+madness+lovecraft&gbv=2&oq=mountains+of+madness+lovecraft&aq=f&aqi=g-S1&aql=&gs_l=img.3..0i24.4470.1890.0.2347.8.1.7.0.0.0.285.245.2-1.1.0...0.0.W_C1z_rfY-k

Is there a very easy way to get a short URL suitable for sharing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either use the URL https://www.google.com/search?q=mountains+of+madness+lovecraft&tbm=isch or you could just use a URL shortener, like [bit.ly](https://bitly.com/).

Note: `tbm=isch` means the search will be done in images.

Comment: I prefer this one: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=mountains+of+madness+lovecraft&tbm=isch

Answer (score 2):

The URL in the form `https://images.google.com/images?q=mountains+of+madness+lovecraft` works
too.

Test: https://images.google.com/images?q=mountains+of+madness+lovecraft

Search tools in Google Images correspond to various modifiers, as you can find out by trying them and checking how the link was changed, for example (below each link, it's showed the modified parameter):

- Color: https://images.google.com/images?q=mountains+of+madness+lovecraft&tbs=ic:specific,isc:red

  - `&tbs=ic:specific,isc:red`
- <s>Date Range https://images.google.com/images?q=mountains+of+madness+lovecraft&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:4/1/2013,cd_max:5/1/2013</s> - custom range is still supported for regular searches; not but no longer for images
- Past year (past month, past week, today): https://images.google.com/images?q=mountains+of+madness+lovecraft&tbs=qdr:y

  - `&tbs=qdr:y`
- Size https://images.google.com/images?q=mountains+of+madness+lovecraft&tbs=isz:l

  - `&tbs=isz:l`

The basic idea is experimenting with the URL - you can always try which parts you can omit.

Comment: The first link is redirected to `https://www.google.com/search?q=mountains+of+madness+lovecraft&tbm=isch`, the same as the accepted [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/27773/88163).

Comment: @Rubén Yes - the answer was posted a few years ago, Google clearly changed some things since then.

Answer (score 0):

I created a very simple web app that cleans Google search result page URLs, links copied from those pages, etc.: [URL Clean](https://urlclean.com).