# Is it possible to create a Google image search URL for a specific size and color and text?

Tags: url, google-image-search, querystring

I'm creating a simple CMS, and I want to let users click a link in the administration panel to search for an image with specific attributes.

These attributes are:

- Specific size (for example 1600*900)
- Specific colors (hexadecimal, for example `#9c27d9`)
- Specific title (for example, *10 effective tips for cleaning your kitchen sink*)

I don't see specific sizes and colors in Google's Image search tools. It only knows predefined colors (green, blue, etc.) and has predefined sizes (large, small, etc.)

Is it possible to create that link?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a window of you web browser in private, save navigation / incognito mode. Ensure that there is no extension enabled.
2. Go to https://www.google.com/advanced_image_search
3. Enter your parameters using the fields and dropdowns
4. Click the button Advanced Search
5. Grab the URL
6. Analyse the query string to correlate the parameter names with the values you entered / selected.
7. Change the values you entered using the Advanced Search form to meet your needs.

Related

- [Anonymize a Google Images URL](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/27772/88163)
- [How should I write the URL for a specific Google Search query?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/39818/88163)